# 'DefaultValue' property was already registered by 'Xceed_Wpf_Toolkit_NumericUpDown`1_12_151463089'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, numericupdown, wpf-extended-toolkit

## Error Description

I've searched for this error but every other topic was involving C# code and metadata/dependency overridings.

But my problem actually involves only and just XAML declarations (of course, it has "MyControl.xaml" and "MyControl.xaml.cs", but nothing that even mention any control that gives those errors).

Also, it **does** compile, the program runs OK, everything is fine, but it gives a build error (tracked in blue) is annoying to see every line envolving *xctk* underlined in blue as if it had something wrong.

If I do:

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown />
```

I get this:

> 'DefaultValue' property was already registered by 'Xceed_Wpf_Toolkit_NumericUpDown'1_12_151463089'

## How to reproduce

Just do anything envolving Xceed WPF Toolkit:

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown />
<xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="something" />
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="something" />
<xctk:IntegerUpDown DefaultValue="0" />
<xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="something" DefaultValue="0" />
```

No aditional C# code involved, still all of above gives the same error.

## Aditional Information

"xctk" is defined this way in my UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    ...other definitions...
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

What could it be related with and what should I check first?

(EDIT)

## More Aditional Information

Just found that DoubleUpDown doesn't raise the error:

`<xctk:DoubleUpDown />`

Comment: I did a test but couldn't reproduce the issue you are having. If you still need help, you can send us an email at support@xceed.com

Comment: Maybe a version issue? How can I check my Xceed version?

Comment: Having exactly this issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it has fixed itself after some updates (Visual Studio 2017, if I remember). I'm not on that project anymore, but I can check next week. Also I remember using the DoubleUpDown for a while and setting its step to 1, tho.

Comment: I have similar issue but it reports the 'IsInvalid' property instead of the 'DefaultValue' (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.11)